# How to run fabric command in a certain environment

Tags: python, fabric

I defined different environments in my module :

`__init__.py`

```
def localdev():
    """
    Work on local dev environment
    """
    env.db_credentials = {'user':'username', 'pass':'passs','name':'mydb'}
    env.uwsgi_command = 'uwsgi'
    env.settings = 'local_dev'
    env.hosts = ['dev@localhost']

dev production():
    pass
```

in `deploy.py`

```
from __future__ import with_statement

import os

from fabric.api import * 
from fabric.decorators import task

@task    
def flush_cache(environment, ):
    """
    Clear memcached cache
    """
    sudo('/etc/init.d/memcached restart', pty=True)
```

`fabfile.py`

```
from mymodule import *
```

How should I run my code in my localdev environment now ?

```
 fab localdev deploy.flush_cache

Fatal error: Command(s) not found:
    localdev

Aborting.
```

Thanks!

Comment: try:
    m = __import__ ('mymodule')
    func = getattr(m, environment)
    func()
except Exception, e:
    pass                          Any better ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to import init.py in fabfile.py. Arguments passed to fabric are used as function names in fabfile.py. As you don't import the module the function doesn't exist and so you get the command not found error.

Comment: The problem is that when we are using classic tasks (without @task) we are running actually two tasks (first one is to update our envs, the second is to run our task). But when using @task decorator other methods are simply ignored. So I will probably write  my own decorator (like update_env) ...